# Creating a lookup field that contains calculation?

Tags: lookup-column

So I created a lookup table, how would go about truncating via a lookup?

For example,

[image]

Choices 56, 56SW, 56FR are using   the same calculation

Choices DDS IDSL, ISDN TR, ISDN are using the same calculation

choices HDSL, HDSL2, HDSL4 are using the same calculation

What would be the best way to go about that....

Is there a way to have the user choose a one of those and then perform the   calculation?

So if user chooses HDSL2 it will do the HDSL calculation, same thing if user   chooses HDSL4 instead it will do the HDSL calculation since HDSL, HDSL2, AND   HDSL4 are the same calculations...

Choices DDS IDSL, ISDN TR, ISDN are using the same calculation

choices HDSL, HDSL2, HDSL4 are using the same calculation So if user chooses HDSL2 it will do the HDSL calculation, same thing if user chooses HDSL4 instead it will do the HDSL calculation since HDSL, HDSL2, AND HDSL4 are the same calculations...

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you have a lookup column on whose values you would like to set a calculated column on.

Lookup columns cannot be referenced in a calculated column. To make this work, create a text column with a similar name to your lookup column, (myLookupColumnText). Copy the text from your lookup column to this new text column. By using a workflow (example [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_28338394.html)) or JQuery

Now, create a calculated column that uses the formula below to determine whether myLookupColumnText contains the text "HDSL" or "56" or "ISD" and write your formula in "success"

=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("mytext",[Column1])), "success", "failure") Determines whether Column1 contains the text "mytext" if yes, returns "success"

=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("HDSL",[myLookupColumnText])), "HDSL is found", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("56",[myLookupColumnText])), "56 is found", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ISD",[myLookupColumnText])),"ISD is found", "none of the above")

You can keep building on the formula like this.

Comment: how do I create a text column with a similar name to your lookup column?

Comment: If your column name is circuittype create a text column 'circuittypetext'. This is just for ease, you can name the text column whatever you like. The idea is to copy the lookup value to this text column to be use in calculated fields.

Comment: what about the statement for if IS number isn't there a restriction for only 8 IF statements? do you have a email address or instant messenger by any chance,... I am so confused.

Comment: Yes, there can only be 7 nested if statements In a formula. But you can have more if you tweak the logic and have non-nested if statements and combine them by &. Sowmya.deenadayal@gmail.com